# Looking for documentation to connect Rasa to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am building a rasa bot, I was using mongodb for tracking bot information. Right now I wanted to shift to cassandra, please provide any documentation

I installed cassandra-driver using pip install cassandra-driver. I could execute sample python file connecting to cassandra db. When I try similar thing in rasa I get this error

```
Anaconda3\envs\install_demo\lib\site-packages\sanic_cors\extension.py:39: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  SANIC_VERSION = LooseVersion(sanic_version)
2023-06-13 15:26:07 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2023-06-13 15:26:07 ERROR    rasa_sdk.executor  - Failed to register package 'actions'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Anaconda3\envs\install_demo\lib\site-packages\rasa_sdk\executor.py", line 262, in register_package
    self._import_submodules(package)
  File "Anaconda3\envs\install_demo\lib\site-packages\rasa_sdk\executor.py", line 225, in _import_submodules
    self._import_module(full_name)
  File "Anaconda3\envs\install_demo\lib\site-packages\rasa_sdk\executor.py", line 239, in _import_module
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "Anaconda3\envs\install_demo\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "Desktop\RASA\chatops-rasa\actions\actions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from actions.help_actions import *
  File "Desktop\RASA\chatops-rasa\actions\help_actions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cassandra'*
```

please help me resolving this

Comment: Please put the effort in and paste text information as text.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any documentation related to connecting Rasa to a Cassandra database.

My suggestion is that you reach out to the Rasa community directly to get assistance from the contributors. Cheers!